# How to display json array data in html after using sendFile in node Js

Tags: html, node.js, json, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxOdD.png)I have an HTML file named as `index.html`.

The file contains a JSON array data as added below.

I want to display this array using div tag, The HTML code is given below :

**Code**

```
//node js code
res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html',{data:JSON.stringify(data)});

//html code 
<% var d = JSON.parse(data); for (var i= 0; i < JSON.parse(data)[0].length; i++) { %>
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-3 border-bottom p-2 chat-select ">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="user-chat-img">
                                <img src="img/user.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold"><%= d[0][i].name %></p>
                                <span>Hello I am DK Singha   </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <% } %>
```

Please suggest me how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found this. 
[res.sendfile in Node Express with passing data along](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027089/res-sendfile-in-node-express-with-passing-data-along)

rewrite.

```js
// NodeJS
const target = '$$$data$$$';
fs.readFile(__dirname+'/index.html', (err, html) => {
    res.send(html.replace(target, JSON.stringify(data)));
});


// HTML
<script>
var data = '$$$data$$$$';
data = JSON.parse(data)[0];
for (var i= 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    console.log(data[i].name);
}
</script>
```

this is working?

Comment: Loop is not working properly and at the place of <% 
var data = '$$$data$$$$'; 
for (var i= 0; i < JSON.parse(data)[0].length; i++) { 
%>  and <%= d[0][i].name %> it is dislaying the same result like <% 
var data = '$$$data$$$$'; 
for (var i= 0; i < JSON.parse(data)[0].length; i++) { 
%> and <%= d[0][i].name %>

Comment: Can you suggest me How can we display data using loop?

Comment: I have added the picture @seunggabi

Comment: @user3834344 okay I understand code. You have to add script append HTML elements

Comment: @user3834344 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703780/adding-multiple-html-elements-in-a-javascript-loop

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use view engine, such as twig, pug or blade. If you are working with Express, it's super easy to setup and use. You would be able to pass your data to your view in your Express router like this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!'});
});
```

And then use your JSON variables in your view, you can see the twig documentation here: [Twig Doc](https://twig.symfony.com/)

For example here, it would be `{{ title }}` or `{{ message }}` to use those variables. You can implement for loop, conditions and more using view engines.

Comment: But I have to do code in Node Js with html and Twig is related to php

Comment: Can you precise your needs, you can achieve this using nodejs html and twig. What is the relation with php ? Can you explain ?